# Angular JS : Filter using textbox and Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

I'm New with angularJS and I just want to filter my data using textbox together with checkbox.

Here is my data:

```
  $scope.array = [
    {name: 'Tobias', lname: 'TLname', company: 'x'},
    {name: 'Jeff', lname: 'JLname', company: 'x'},
    {name: 'Brian', lname: 'BLname', company: 'x'},
    {name: 'Igor', lname: 'ILname', company: 'y'},
    {name: 'James', lname: 'JLname', company: 'z'},
    {name: 'Brad', lname: 'BLname', company: 'y'}
  ];
```

All I want is if I going to choose **x** from checkbox it will show the rows related with **Tobias** **Jeff** **Brian** and if I'm going to uncheck the checkbox and type **br**, **Brian** and **Brad** will show but if I'm going to check the **x** checkbox only  **Bryan** should show.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would use filters to accomplish this.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w4XqV/16/

Markup:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div>Search by Name: <input type="text" ng-model="filters.search"></div>
       <div>Show only Company X: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filters.x" ng-change="actions.updateCompany()"/>           
       </div>
       <div ng-repeat="arr in array | filter:filters.search | filter:{company: filters.company}">
           <span ng-bind="arr.name"></span>
       </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.filters = {
        x: false,
        company: '',
        search: ''
    };

    $scope.actions = {
        updateCompany: function () {
            if($scope.filters.x) {
                $scope.filters.company = 'x';
            } else {
                 $scope.filters.company = '';   
            }
        }
    };


    $scope.array = [
    {name: 'Tobias', lname: 'TLname', company: 'x'},
    {name: 'Jeff', lname: 'JLname', company: 'x'},
    {name: 'Brian', lname: 'BLname', company: 'x'},
    {name: 'Igor', lname: 'ILname', company: 'y'},
    {name: 'James', lname: 'JLname', company: 'z'},
    {name: 'Brad', lname: 'BLname', company: 'y'}
  ];
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Could it be possible if I check **x** and **y** it will show the all the related data on it? please see: http://jsfiddle.net/w4XqV/17/

Comment: can somebody help me?

Comment: please help me how to show related records if I check **x** and **y**

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl2">
<div>
  <input type="text" ng-model="myfilter" placeholder="filter">
  <br>avilable:<input type="checkbox" ng-model="check" checked value="avilable">
  <br>
  <span ng-click="sortby('name')">name</span><span ng-click="sortby('country')">country</span>
</div>
<p></p>
<div class="row1" ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:myorder | filter:check | filter:myfilter">
  <span class="row2">
  {{x.name}}
</span>
  <span class="row2">
  {{x.country}}
</span>
</div>
<h1>{{myfilter}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller('ctrl2', function ($scope) {
$scope.sortby = function (x) {
    $scope.myorder = x;
}

$scope.names = [
    { name: 'Jani', country: 'Norway', available: true },
    { name: 'Carl', country: 'Sweden', available: false },
    { name: 'Margareth', country: 'England', available: true },
    { name: 'Hege', country: 'Norway', available: true },
    { name: 'Joe', country: 'Denmark', available: false },
    { name: 'Gustav', country: 'Sweden', available: false },
    { name: 'Birgit', country: 'Denmark', available: false },
    { name: 'Mary', country: 'England', available: true },
    { name: 'Kai', country: 'Norway', available: false }
];
```

});